# Handle property of a component in window.onclick

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a component where I have the enableButtons property that is set to true when I click on an ion-menu label. I would like if I click anywhere else this property to revert to false. I tried this piece of code:

```
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
  enableButtons: boolean;

  constructor(private router: Router,private menu: MenuController) {
    this.enableButtons= false;
    
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if(this.enableButtons){  //this.enableButtons tells me that is undefined
        this.enableButtons = false;
      }
    }
  }

  async presentModalEliminaItems() {
    this.menu.close();  
    this.enableButtons = true;      
  }
```

The problem is that "this" in the function window.onClick is of type Window and not of type ProfilePage . How can I solve it ?

**SOLVED** : i have used the class Renderer2 of Angular instead of window.onclick:

```
@ViewChild('aEliminaVideo') toggleButton: ElementRef;

  this.renderer.listen('window', 'click',(e:Event)=>{
    if(e.target!==this.toggleButton.nativeElement && this.enableButtons == true){
      this.enableButtons = false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Did you initialize the `enableButtons` value? The only place in the code you provided is in the `async presentModelEliminaItems` function.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just `undefined` issue from this code snippets, you have to move your code to `ngOnInit(){}`. It is a runtime issue i.e `Constructor` vs `OnInit`. You can also add the `non null assertion operator` to your declared properties by attaching `!` mark to your properties, telling TypeScript that you know that your properties will recieve value at runtime and thus skip strict checking.
Such as: `enableButtons!: boolean;`

Comment: hi Rick, doesn't work, I figured out the problem. "this" is an object of type window in the function window.onclick

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the property in your definition:

```
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
  enableButtons = false;

  ...
}
```

the boolean type will be inferred automatically with the assignment.

Comment: hi Rick, doesn't work, I figured out the problem. "this" is an object of type window in the function window.onclick